# Convert async iterable to sync

Tags: python-asyncio

I have:

- a sync function `f` that takes an `Iterable` as input.
- an `AsyncIterable` input.

How can I convert the latter to a (sync) `Iterable` to pass it to `f` from an async caller?

Example:

```py
import asyncio


async def asquare(n):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.01 * n)
    return n * n


def first_even(numbers):
    return next(n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0)


async def main(numbers):
    squares = ...  # ???

    # TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
    # squares = (await asquare(n) for n in numbers)

    # RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
    # squares = (asyncio.run(asquare(n)) for n in numbers)

    # RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
    # squares = (asyncio.get_running_loop().run_until_complete(asquare(n)) for n in numbers)

    return first_even(squares)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(asyncio.run(main([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])))
```

Notes:

- The iterable should not be iterated eagerly in the caller (e.g. with `await asyncio.gather(...)`) as it may be long/infinite.
- I am aware of [nest_asyncio](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio) but I'm interested in a solution that doesn't involve patching asyncio.
- Ideally a solution should not require spawning other thread(s) or creating new event loop(s) (unless it's impossible without doing so).

Comment: I don't think this is possible without unpleasant hacks of some sort. The premise of asyncio is that it's async functions that are calling other async functions, and your `first_even` is simply not async. That's a problem, as it would essentially block the event loop if it could somehow exhaust the async iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for async generator ([async generators](https://superfastpython.com/asynchronous-generators-in-python/#How_to_Use_an_Asynchronous_Generator)). So you could do something like this.

```
import asyncio

async def asquare(n):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.01 * 1.0)
    return n * n

def first_even(numbers):
    return next(n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0)

async def async_gen(numbers):
    for n in numbers:
        yield await asquare(n)

async def main(numbers):
    squares = [item async for item in async_gen(numbers)]
    return first_even(squares)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(asyncio.run(main([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])))
```

Comment: Thanks but this violates the first constraint ("The iterable should not be iterated eagerly in the caller").